# Array(Array'First) "array index check might fail"

Tags: ada, codepeer

While analyzing an Ada codebase with CodePeer, the tool is reporting that *"array index check might fail"* at a line that does this:

```
Param(Param'First) := ....
```

Param is a passed-in `out` parameter - and it's of an array type.

My understanding is that Ada carries the array sizes and valid index ranges at runtime (in order to perform range checks)... I can't see how any Ada array can violate its range check by accessing index `array'First`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare an array with an empty range,

```
array(1..0)
array(10..5)
array(1337..-1)
```

etc.

In this case, Param'First would be greater than Param'Last, and the index check would fail.

I guess Param is of an unconstrained array type, like String, f.eks?

```
type String is array(Positive range <>) of Character;
```

any object of the type could then be declared as an empty string:

```
Foo : String(1..0);
```

and then passed as parameter to your subprogram

Comment: I understand - but if you don't mind me asking.... why would one do that? I mean, why would Ada even allow such an instantiation to compile?

Comment: Functions can return array objects, like `Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line`. Sometimes, the line is empty (if the user only pressed enter, for example). In that case, the array returned would also need to be empty.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent the problem by giving your unconstrained array type a dynamic predicate, which says that the array can't be empty:

```ada
subtype Non_Empty_String is String
  with Dynamic_Predicate => Non_Empty_String'Length >= 1;
```

Comment: Alternatively you can check the length of the array before referencing its index values.